# Кто-то говорит( )что да. Кто-то говорит( )что нет

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, лексика, союзы

Нужны ли запятые перед союзами "что"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сложноподчиненные предложения, перед "что" запятая ставится, как как дальше идут слова *да* и *нет*, выражающие утверждение и отрицание (так их называет [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129#pp129)).
**Кто-то говорит, что да. Кто-то говорит, что нет.**

[**Нет**](http://rudictionary.com/kuzhecov/Net-16554.html#gsc.tab=0) — частица, употребляется как отрицательный ответ на вопрос или как выражение несогласия (может выступать в качестве предложения; противоп.: да). *Есть будешь? — **Нет*** (Я не буду есть). *Вы поедете на симпозиум? — **Нет*** (Я не поеду).

> Бойкий офицер Петроковский, в первый раз видевший Хаджи-Мурата, через переводчика спросил его, понравился ли ему Тифлис.
> — Айя, — сказал он.
> — **Он говорит, что да**, — отвечал переводчик.
> Л. Н. Толстой. Хаджи-Мурат

> — Когда операция? — спросила Глушенкова.
> — Приблизительно через неделю.
> — А Настя знает?
> — Да, конечно.
> — Боится?
> — **Говорит, что нет**, — улыбнулась Татьяна. — Но ты же знаешь, все боятся.
> М. Милованов. Рынок тщеславия

В примерах слова "да" и "нет" заменяют полные ответы на вопросы (они понятны только в контексте).
*Он говорит, что ему понравился Тифлис*. [Она] *Говорит, что не боится*.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @CloudHero  На сайте принято отмечать все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец треугольник мне еще недоступен, но галочку проставил )